# Is it possible to share multiple photos in a single action?

Tags: photos

Is there a way to select a group of photos and share them, with Facebook or email, all at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can by email but not to facebook. Open a new email message and click on the attach icon. Once you've attached one pic then click on the Attached icon again and so on. Think there's an app available via the Marketplace you can use to upload multiple images to facebook.